# Optimizing finding and counting proper divisors in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This code needs to run under 7000ms or it times out and I am trying to learn ruby so I am here to see if anyone has any ideas that could optimize this code. Or if you can just let me know which functions in this code take the most time so I can concentrate on the parts that will do the most good.

The questions to solve is that you have to tell if the number of divisors for any umber is odd or even.

For n=12 the divisors are [1,2,3,4,6,12] – 'even'

For n=4 the divisors are [1,2,4] – 'odd'

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

```ruby
def oddity(n)
  div(n) % 2 == 0 ? (return 'even'): (return 'odd')
end

def div(num)
  divs = []
  (1..num).each{|x| if (num % x == 0) then divs << x end}
  return divs.length
end
```

Comment: You are essentially counting to n n times. Think about whether or not there is a way to do fewer loops.

Comment: I am not sure I see the double loop? I see that 1..num is a loop that runs the modular function to num. But that only has me looping from 1 to num a single time.

Comment: If you are searching for factors, you only need to count up to n/2. If you are searching for prime factors, you only need to count to the square root of 2. I would suggest decomposing n into prime factors and calculating the number of ways those prime factors can be multiplied together.

Comment: @Alex did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

The key observation here is that you need only **the number** of divisors, rather than the divisors themselves. Thus, a fairly simple solution is to decompose the number to primes, and check how many combinations can we form.

```
require 'mathn'

def div(num)
  num.prime_division.inject(1){ |prod, n| prod *= n[1] + 1 } 
end
```

`prime_division` returns a list of pairs, where the first is the prime and the second is its exponent. E.g.:

```
12.prime_division
=> [[2, 2], [3, 1]]
```

We simply multiply the exponents, adding 1 to each, to account for the case where this prime wasn't taken.

Comment: I completely missed your answer before! I'll report it in my benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

Since performance is an issue, let's compare the OP's solution with @standelaune's and @dimid's.

```
require 'prime'
require 'fruity'

n = 100_000
m = 20
tst = m.times.map { rand(n) }
  #=> [30505, 26103, 53968, 24108, 78302, 99141, 22816, 67504, 10149, 28406,
  #    18294, 92203, 73157, 5444, 24928, 65154, 24850, 64219, 68310, 64951]

def op(num) # Alex
  divs = []
  (1..num).each { |x| if (num % x == 0) then divs << x end }
  divs.length
end

def test_op(tst) # Alex
  tst.each { |n| op(n) }
end

def pd(num) # divid
  num.prime_division.inject(1){ |prod, n| prod *= n[1] + 1 } 
end

def test_pd(tst) #divid
  tst.each { |n| nfacs_even?(n) }
end

def div(num) # standelaune
  oddity = false
  (1..num).each{|x| if (num % x == 0) then oddity = !oddity end}
  oddity ? "odd" : "even"
end

def test_div(tst) # standelaune
  tst.each { |n| div(n) }
end
```

```
compare do
  _test_op  { test_op tst  } 
  _test_div { test_div tst }
  _test_pd  { test_pd tst  }
end

Running each test 16 times. Test will take about 56 seconds.
_test_pd is faster than _test_div by 480x ± 100.0
_test_div is similar to _test_op
```

I'm not suprised that `divid`'s method smokes the others, as `prime_division` uses (an instance of) the default prime generator, [Prime::Generator23](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime/Generator23.html#method-i-next), That generator is coded in C and is fast relative to other generators in `Prime` subclasses.

Comment: The combination thing is useless. Just add one to each exponent and multiply them.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by optimising your algorithm.

You don't have to check all numbers below the number you are examining. It is enough to split your number in to it´s prime components. Then it is a simple matter of combinatorics to determine how many possible divisors there are.

One way to get all prime components could be:

```
PRIME_SET = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
def factorize(n)
  cut_off = Math.sqrt(n)
  parts = []
  PRIME_SET.each do |p|
    return parts if p > cut_off
    if n % p == 0
      n = n/p
      parts << p
      redo
    end
  end
  raise 'To large number for current PRIME_SET'
end
```

Then computing the number of possible can be done in a number of different ways and there are probably ways of doing it without even computing them. But here is a naive implementation.

```
def count_possible_divisors(factors)
  divisors = Set.new
  (1..factors.length-1).each do |i|
    factors.combination(i).each do |comb|
      divisors.add(comb.reduce(1, :*))
    end
  end
  divisors.length + 2 # plus 2 for 1 and n
end
```

This should result in less work than what you are doing. But for large numbers this is a hard task to achieve.

Comment: How would you know in advance how large `PRIME_SET` would have to be?  If the number to factor were, say, `135,373`, and the exception '"Too large number for current PRIME_SET' were raised, what would you do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your algorithm, here is an optimization.

```
def div(num)
  oddity = false
  (1..num).each{|x| if (num % x == 0) then oddity = !oddity end}
  oddity ? "odd" : "even"
end
```

Comment: You're not likely to find many factors between `num/2+1` and `num-1`. Actually, you need only check between 1 and `Math.sqrt(num).floor`. Each factor `n` among those counts as two, as `num/n` is also factor. If `num` is a perfect square you need to subtract 1 from the total, to avoid double-counting the square root of `num`.